# make: Circular mysh <- mysh dependency dropped

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, makefile

I have a very simple `Makefile` which is supposed to do the same task as `gcc -o mysh mysh.c -Wall` but I am receiving `make: Circular mysh <- mysh dependency dropped.` however the executable is created and works fine. Do you know how to remove this message?

```
C=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall

all: mysh
mysh: mysh
        ${C} ${CFLAGS} -o mysh mysh.c

clean:
        rm -f mysh
run: mysh
        ./mysh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
mysh: mysh
```

into

```
mysh: mysh.c
```

That should do it.

You had `mysh` dependent on `mysh` which is a circular dependency.

Comment: @Mona, if someone gives you an answer that's acceptable, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark just below the down arrow.

Comment: I guess that the dependency ought to be `mysh: mysh.c` (i.e. `mysh` must be rebuilt according to the given rule whenever `mysh.c` is modified).

Comment: @Virgile, yes, that would also be a valid rule. The only difference would be that 'make' would respond 'mysh up to date' if mysh.c hadn't changed. In the version with no dependencies 'make' would always recompile mysh.c whether it needed it or not. In a simple Makefile like this, I would argue both are reasonable.

Comment: @CharlieBurns, if you don't put any dependency for mysh, unless it is a `.PHONY` target (which is not the case here), it will _never_ be recompiled.

Comment: @Virgile, you are right, I will fix the answer. Thank you very much.